# Cannot Create NFTs on Localhost

Tags: metaplex, nft, sugar, bundlr

I'm trying to create some NFTs on localhost for testing purposes. I am currently trying to use sugar cli for this.
However, I'm getting the following error with shadow drive and a similar one with Bundlr:

Error running command (re-run needed): ShadowDrive is only supported on devnet or mainnet

What would be the best way to do this? Is there a way to replicate NFTs from Devnet?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Shadow Drive issue, you'll probably need to ask them, but if you want to replicate NFTs from devnet on your localhost, you can use the `--clone` argument as many times as needed, ie:

```
$ solana-test-validator --url devnet --clone <NFT_MINT1> --clone <NFT_TOKEN_ACCOUNT1> --clone <NFT_MINT2> ...
```